# How to restrict access to API Gateway from external GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor, google-api-gateway

How to restrict access to API Gateway from external GCP?
Cloud Armor can only use for Load Balancer.

I created GCP API Gateway(backend is Flask application on App Engine).
And I want to restrict access from external GCP Project.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add ingress filters on API Gateway for now (I got the news this morning!). You will be able to put API Gateway as a backend of your Load Balancer, but you will still continue to be able to have a direct access to API Gateway.

In the future, I imagine a similar feature as [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress) where you can set the ingress settings to internal or internal and cloud load balancing.

Stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you!
I am looking forward to update of service.

Comment: You can check latest release notes of products in the official documentation, i.e. Release notes for [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/release-notes), [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/release-notes)

Comment: Any update on this? Or any trick available?

Comment: A friend of mine should have a meeting with the API Gateway (new) PM. I asked him. I let you know if I have news.

Comment: Update here! No improvement for API Gateway soon, but a lot of released on Apigee to make it more usable by small users. And Apigee is connected to the VPC, therefore, no issues. At least 2 quarters are required to implement the new features.

Comment: Any updates on this? If not, is there a some other solution for it?

Comment: it is 2023 any updates?

Comment: Sadly the team is unreachable... I don't know what will be the future of that product