# How to allow only certain IP addresses access to the google app engine via API Gateway hosted in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, swagger, openapi, api-gateway

I have setup an API gateway in GCP for a client to access my server/app engine. But I want to make sure that the API Gateway is only available for that specific client. I want to do that by restricting requests based on IP address. So I only allow clients whose IP address have been white listed can access the server via the gateway. I want add this restriction based on IP address in the OpenAPI `.yaml` file.

Here is an example of the `.yaml` file I am using.

```
# openapi2-appengine.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: rest-api
  description: API Gateway
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - http
  - https
produces:
  - text/html
  - application/json
x-google-backend:
  address: https://gcp.appspot.com/
  jwt_audience: 12345678
paths:
  /get_data:
    get:
      summary: GET data
      description: To get data
      produces:
        - application/json
      operationId: Data
      responses:
        200:
          description: A successful response
        403:
          description: Access forbidden
```

Comment: Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67786747/how-to-restrict-access-to-api-gateway-from-external-gcp), you can't add ingress filters on API Gateway. So to allow only specific client IP address that can access to your server/App Engine via the gateway you need to use [API Tokens](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticate-service-account#making_an_authenticated_request). With a token, you could use [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview) to restrict access.

Comment: You can also configure the [Identity Aware Proxy (IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-app-engine#configure_iap) to secure your server/app. Then check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-app-engine) for more details.

Comment: I have configured the IAP to secure my app engine/server. But the problem is the client is unable to authenticate using the IAP. Therefore, I set up a API Gateway to allow the client to reach the specific route without any need for authentication using IAP. But at the same time, the API Gateway is not secure

Comment: Can you try this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto).